# jquery fancybox 2 iframe send data to parent via post

Tags: jquery, django, iframe, fancybox

I need to pass data from fancybox iframe to my django view using post.
I set the iframe title as "a href" link that the user can click on.

this is the code for the fancybox:

```
    $(".fancybox-company").fancybox({
    width       : '75%',
    height      : '75%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    fitToView   : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    type : 'iframe',
    beforeLoad: function() {
        var id = $(this.element).data('company-id');
        this.title = "<a href=\"\" id=company-iframe>Add to your list</a>";
    }
});
```

and this is the code that listens on click events:

```
$( ".company-iframe" ).on( 'click', function ( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var id = event.target.href;

    $.post( "/company/selection", { id : id }, function ( json ) {

      // ...

    } );
```

this is not being called, i need to pass the click event from the iframe to the parent and pass the company id as input.

what am i missing?

10x

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing csrf token. It's a [django mechanism](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) for preventing Cross Site Request Forgeries. If you have csrf enabled in your middleware classes than in every post request you have to provide 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' in your data. You can access it from cookie or right in your template , using {% csrf_token %} tag.

After you achieve this token in your template, you need to modify your js function like

```
$( ".company-iframe" ).on( 'click', function ( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var csrfmiddlewaretoken = $('input[name=\"csrfmiddlewaretoken\"]').val();
    var id = event.target.href;

    $.post( "/company/selection", 
             { id : id , csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfmiddlewaretoken},
             function ( json ) {

      // ...

    } );
```